# Are objects copied using List<T>.Add, or simply "mapped"?

Tags: c#, collections

I've come across some confusing behavior while using `Lists` in C#.  If I add a collection (I've tested with both `List<T>` and `Array`) of a given type to a `List` (i.e. `List<List<int>>`), modifying the child `List` will also modify the contents of the parent `List` to which it was added.  However, if I add an object that isn't a collection (i.e. a `bool` or an `int`) to a `List`, modifying the object itself will NOT modify the contents of the `List` to which it was added.  I've included some sample code below:

```
List<List<int>> intList = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> ints = new List<int>();

ints.Add(12345);
intList.Add(ints);
Console.WriteLine(intList[0].Count); //intList[0].Count is 1

ints.Clear();
Console.WriteLine(intList[0].Count); //intList[0].Count is 0
```

It seems that in the above example, the `ints` collection is simply "mapped" to `intList[0]`, so when you modify the `ints` collection itself, you are also modifying `intList[0]`, because they are the same object.  This contrasts with the next example:

```
List<bool> boolList = new List<bool>();
bool bigBool = false;

boolList.Add(bigBool);
Console.WriteLine(boolList[0]); //boolList[0] is false

bigBool = true;
Console.WriteLine(boolList[0]); //boolList[0] is...still false??
```

In the above example, it seems that rather than being mapped to `boolList[0]`, `bigBool` is COPIED to `boolList[0]`.  So `boolList[0]` is a copy of `bigBool`, and they are two separate objects.

So my question is: why do there seem to be two separate functionalities of `List<T>.Add`, depending on what type is being added to the `List`?  I've checked MSDN, but I couldn't find any mention of this behavior.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the kind of object.

Value types will be copied. With reference types the reference will be used.

Integers, booleans, `DateTime` are value types, for example (structs are value types) and `string`, `List<T>` are reference types (classes are reference types).

See [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) on MSDN for details.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question! I didn't know there were different kinds of types...it seems a little confusing, but good to know.

Comment: I would also point out that `string` (besides it is reference type) is also **immutable type**. So if `string` was used in the OP's second example, the value inside the list would not be changed as well.

Comment: @mipe34 - The variable is not immutable. The _string_ is.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it like equality, just the same like:

```
var added = myObject;
```

If the object is a value type (like numbers, etc.), or is immutable, like `string`, then it's copied. If it's a non-immutable reference type, like almost all class instances, then it just gets another reference to the same object instance.

See below for thorough MSDN reference:

- [Passing Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx)